# Using let on mutating variable

Tags: swift

I have a simple custom class that for the sake of simplicity in the example lets say it contains a single property that is an array of arrays of strings.  It has a single method that moves the first object from one array to another.  Ignore the missing initializer, this is a truncated version of an existing class I've written.

```
class MyClass: NSObject
{
    var strings:Array< Array< String > >

    func makeMove(fromArray:Int, toArray:Int)
    {
        var from = strings[fromArray] as Array< String >
        var to = strings[toArray]

        let top = from[0]
        to.append(top)
        from.removeAtIndex(0)

        towers[fromTower] = from
        towers[toTower] = to
    }
}
```

If I declare a new instance of `MyClass` and call this single method on it, I get a compiler warning stating that the instance was never modified and should be made a `let` instead of `var`.

```
var myInstance = MyClass()    //Warning
myInstance.makeMove(0, toArray:1)


let myInstance = MyClass()    //No warning
myInstance.makeMove(0, toArray:1)
```

Interestingly enough, even though in the second instance it is a `let`, which should be a constant, the instance does in fact get mutated when `makeMove` is called on it.

Whats wrong in this case?  Should I use a `let`, or is the compiler not properly recognizing that it is a mutating function?

Comment: Additionally to what BaseZen said, you are copying the array when declaring `var from = strings[fromArray]...` because arrays are value types. You can modify the original array by just using `strings[fromArray] = ...`

Comment: Changing the `strings` property inside the value type `MyClass` does not qualify as a mutation. If `MyClass` were a struct it would be a mutation and you'd have to call `makeMove` a `mutating func`.

Comment: I'm getting off-topic, but combining what @Kametrixom said along with `removeAtIndex` returning the removed object, your `makeMove` method can be simplified greatly. `let movingObject = strings[fromArray].removeAtIndex(0); strings[toArray].append(movingObject)`

Comment: @Kametrixom But don't be allergic to array assignment. The Swift compiler is copy-on-write only. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html See "Assignment and Copy Behavior for Strings, Arrays, and Dictionaries"

Comment: @BaseZen Yeah I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you understand reference types versus value types.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

The `let` keyword prevents mutation to the latter, not the former. Think of a `let` reference variable as: the reference (memory address) that the variable refers to cannot change, but the contents of that memory *can*.

So the warning is trying to tell you that you never re-assign the reference `myInstance` to another object, but your declaration allows for the possibility.

If your *design* is such that `myInstance` should always refer to the object it was first assigned to, let the compiler help you by denoting it as `let`. Then feel free to pass the reference around and change the object's contents as needed using any copy of the reference.

Comment: Ok, I get the difference between reference vs value.  I guess I just read a little to shallow into the swift book's initial description of `let` vs. `var`.  I come from straight c and C++ programming and was taught to be const-correct always, so Apple's push on using `let` and `var` correctly looked nice to me.  I guess it is a little more simplistic than using `const T *` or `T * const` or any of the other numerous permutations of those keywords.

Comment: Off-topic: Like Steve Jobs said many times - think different :-) It's not C, C++ nor Objective-C.

Comment: If I never see another `const * T * const ** T` it will be too soon. (The foregoing evaluates to T squared by const squared raised to the 3rd power in a Euclidean compiler space.)

Comment: Ok with that is there a way for me to tell the compiler "I want this to be a reference to an immutable value" rather than "an immutable reference to a value" as `let` appears to be?

Comment: Quick search reveals https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 as of last year (Aug 15 2014) : "You may be thinking that it could be valuable, then, to have a case where a class is completely immutable. ...Today, you can write an immutable class in Swift by using only immutable stored properties and avoiding exposing any APIs that can modify state. ... Swift does not currently provide any language mechanism to enforce class immutability (e.g. on subclasses) the way it enforces immutability for struct and enum." I cannot speak to Swift 2.0 but doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

To conclude, here is what I think you want, with a suggestion from [wjl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446843/wjl):

```
class MyClass {
    var strings : [[String]] = []

    func makeMove(fromArray from: Int, toArray to: Int) {
        let item = strings[from].removeAtIndex(0)
        strings[to].append(item)
    }
}

let a = MyClass()
a.strings = [["Hi", "H", "A", "C"], ["He", "Ab", "To", "Hehe"]]
a.makeMove(fromArray: 0, toArray: 1)
a.strings           // [["H", "A", "C"], ["He", "Ab", "To", "Hehe", "Hi"]]

// a = MyClass()    // error: cannot assign to value: 'a' is a 'let' constant
```

You can still change that instance of the object, but you cannot change the object, `a` is pointing to